# Android App close and reopen start at beginning again

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have created a simple app for android, that uses buttons to navigate different activities the app starts at page 1, you click on page 2 or 3 button etc and that starts the required activity, simple.

What im having problems with (more of annoyance than problem) when you click HOME or come out of the app, because android doesn't kill the app straight away it is keeping the page you are on remembered and is opening the app at activity 2 or 3 for example. I want the app when closed to go back to the beginning of the app again and open at 1, i can go back to 1 by clicking back but this is really not what i wanted.

I hope someone can read this and understand, simplest solution possible please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is use the Activity lifecycle to your advantage. When a screen is hidden for any reason, its `onPause` method gets called. When it's displayed again, `onResume` gets called. However, `onResume` is called even the first time a new Activity is displayed. Another problem is that `onPause` is called when transitioning between Activities.

So you ultimately want to "restart" the app when the last Activity's `onPause` and `onResume` are called in succession. Try this class, and have all of your Activity's extend this instead of Activity.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private static BaseActivity lastPausedActivity = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        lastPausedActivity = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        if(this == lastPausedActivity) {
            lastPausedActivity = null;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
            startActivity( intent );
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, so it may need a few tweaks, but the logic should be sound.

Comment: I have created this class and then used it in the code for the other classes and the app starts up initially but then as soon as i try to go to the other page it springs back to the first page again and then seems to go in a loop of first page second page first page etc till the app crashes

Comment: `getTaskId()` may have been a poor choice. I thought it may be unique between Activities, but it may not be. Try hold the Activity instead of the taskId (note that this is generally a bad idea, but just to make sure my logic is fine). I'll update my code.

Comment: Oh I see what I missed. `lastPausedActivity` needs to be reset after we get inside the `if` check.

Comment: This is perfect, just changed the code in the program and it works wonders, every time I 'close' the app (using home or other options) it goes back to the home when I reopen it. Thank you for your help and clear instructions

Comment: Happy to help Tim. I'm curious though, did you stick with the `getTaskId()` solution or are you using the code I have above now? I'd try again with `getTaskId()` if you're not, as holding a static reference to an `Activity` is almost always a bad idea.